# How to train (append) new trained data with existing spacy model using python

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I'm new for spacy and python ,by using below code i have create new customized model.But my requirement is how to append new trained data with existing (my customized) model.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ('Who is Kofi Annan?', {
        'entities': [(8, 18, 'people')]
    }),
     ('Who is Steve Jobs?', {
        'entities': [(7, 17, 'people')]
    }),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', {
        'entities': [(7, 13, 'location'), (18, 24, 'location')]
    })
]

    nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
    print("Created blank 'en' model")
```

Above code create customized model, But i need is to append new trained data into existing model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update an existing model you just need to load that model instead of the blank model and start from there:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

There are a few things to be aware of, so take a look at the usage guide here: https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-ner

Comment: Thanks aab for response,my need is append new training data into existing model not to load existing model....Thanks

Comment: See the full example here, which loads an existing model and extends it with new data: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py (It's the first example in the linked usage docs.)